# What are each of the functions in this line of code in angular js alluding or referring to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
myMod.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.provider('greeting', function() {
    this.$get = function() {
      return function(name) {
        alert("Hello, " + name);
      };
    };
  });
});
```

This is an angularjs code for providing me a custom service named greeting to use.I will inject this service into my controller in my code.The code is working fine for me.What i am confused is about the number of times the word function is called in this particular section of code.Please can anyone say what each of the functions is alluding to.For example the function in the line `this.$get = function()` is referring to the $get method of the provider method.What does the function in the line `$provide.provider('greeting', function()` refers to?And i also dont seem to know what the other functions refers to?Also as a side note i learnt about a type of function called 'anonymous' functions.What are they and why are they called anonymous?Is not defining a function by a specific name is somehow beneficial to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the code below which may be more illustrative. It is equivalent to your code.

Explanation:

1. The `.config` method is called on the `myMod` module. Its argument is a `function` used to configure the module. In this case a new `provider` is added to the module.
2. The second function does the job. I *registers* a *new* `provider` on your `module`. In order to do that, this registering function requires a *name* for this new provider, as well as a `provider object`. The object can have a `$get method` (a method is just another function ). In your case this is achieved by calling `this.$get`.
3. The provider's `$get method` will be called when a new instance of your provider is created. The `$get method`  *returns* the actual function that is to be used. In your case it is the function `greeting`.

---

```
    myMod.config( registerProvider($provider) );

    /////
    function registerProvider($provider){
      var 
      providerName = 'greeting',
      provider = providerObject;

      $provider(providerName, providerObject);   
    }

    var providerObject = {
      $get: function() {return greeting}   
    };

    function greeting(name){
      alert('Hello');
    }
```